# Got a list of all publishers and books they have given out, but how do i get a list of all publishers, also the one that havent published anything?

Tags: mysql, select

Ok so i have this database:

- CONSULTANT(**cons_id**, firstname, lastname, epost)
- BOOK(**book_id**, title, published_year, publisher_id*)
- PUBLISHER(**publisher_id**, publisher_name, adresse, phone)
- AUTHOR(**author_id**, firstname, lastname, birth_year, year_of_death, nationality)
- BOOK_AUTHOR(book_id*, author_id*)

So i now got a select query in mysql

```
SELECT title, publisher_name, p.publisher_id
FROM book b 
LEFT JOIN publisher p 
ON p.publisher_id = b.publisher_id;
```

This gets me all the books and all the publisher names but i only get the publishers that have published books, not the publishers that has not.

Its total of 8 publishers in the database i got publisher_id 2, 3, 5, 7 and 8.

Comment: Swap the selection order. You are only selecting books and matching them with publishers. You want to select publishers and match them with books.

Comment: Or change to `RIGHT JOIN`. But `LEFT JOIN` is more common.

Comment: Please post your sample data.  If its too big for here then use a dbfiddle.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! RIGHT JOIN was the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT publisher.publisher_id, publisher.publisher_name, count(*) count_book FROM book 
LEFT JOIN publisher on book.publisher_id = publisher.publisher_id
GROUP BY publisher.publisher_id, publisher.publisher_name
____ count_book ____
```